# Cannot implicitly convert type 'RazorEngine.Text.RawString' to 'string'

Tags: c#, razor, view

Instead of having to define it every single time, I've done a subtemplate to determine whether a product is: in stock, out of stock, discontinued etc.

So in my main template, I want to display something based on the returned value.

When I use `@Raw(Model.TemplateUtil.Subtemplate("SubAvailabilityCheck"))` I get the proper value (ie. IN STOCK or COMING SOON etc.)

but when I add the following to declare my variable:

```
string stockCheck = Raw(Model.TemplateUtil.Subtemplate("SubAvailabilityCheck"));
```

It gives me: ERROR:Cannot implicitly convert type 'RazorEngine.Text.RawString' to 'string'

When I convert to string it outputs the entire html code with the default html comments that mark the beginning and end of the template etc. Where as RAW strips everything but the content.

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0):

The `Raw()` function simply wraps the string you pass it in a `RawString`, which tells RazorEngine not to HTML-escape it.

As the error is trying to tell you, a `RawString` isn't a string and cannot be stored in a `string` variable.

Change the variable to be of type `RawString`.

Comment: Had tried that, gives me a compile error:
The type or namespace name 'RawString' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Trying adding an `using RazorEngine.Text;` statement? If you really want to store the value into a `String`, you might be able to just called `.ToString()` on it to get its value.

Comment: @JeffBridgman: Calling `ToString()` will defeat the purpose of `Raw()`; it will return the original string.